# cannot read property 'length' of undefined react ERROR

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I need your help with this project, since it gives me an error and I do not know what the problem may be, I really appreciate the help you can give me to solve this project.

```
ChatBox.hashString
C:/xampp/htdocs/chatinterno/asembis/src/Pages/ChatBox/ChatBox.js:548
  545 | }
  546 | hashString = str => {
  547 |         let hash =0
> 548 |         for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      | ^  549 |         hash += Math.pow(str.charCodeAt(i) * 31, str.length - i)
  550 |         hash = hash & hash // Convert to 32bit integer
  551 |     }
```

Comment: Can you add the function call of hashString along with the question?

Comment: `str` is undefined. Where do you call the `hashString` function? Can you do a `console.log(str)` above the line 548 and tell me what do you get